Comparing rows of data when there is a duplicate in column
I am looking for help on accomplishing something beyond my current skills.  In column A there are several serial numbers, if there any duplicate serial numbers within Column A, I would like the rows these duplicates are in to be compared against each other and have anything different highlighted. These rows should be near identical with the same value in each column, but if there is something different in any when comparing the values in each column I would like it highlighted.
I now have a start, but its not dynamic, which it needs to be.  This code works, but it is comparing every 2 lines and looping down.  I only need it to compare rows where values match in column A.
    Dim rng As Range, rngDiff As Range
    Set rng = Range("D2:AZ3")              'start here


    Do While Application.CountA(rng) > 0  'loop while have content
        Set rngDiff = Nothing   'reset range
        On Error Resume Next    'ignore "No cells were found" error if no differences
        Set rngDiff = rng.ColumnDifferences(Comparison:=rng.Cells(1))
        On Error GoTo 0         'stop ignoring errors
        If Not rngDiff Is Nothing Then
            rngDiff.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'color all differences
            rngDiff.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(2) 'two rows down
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True  

Any help appreciated!

Sounds like conditional formatting and a formula could be enough.  Match() and Index() can support you, and conditional formatting on the results to highlight.  If you are working through VBA, please EDIT YOUR POST to include the code you've tried.

Note:

The code currently highlights only two duplicated rows. Please revise the code to handle more than two duplicated rows in your table.

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, diffRng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' consolidate data with Dict object
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set objDic(sKey) = Application.Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 1))
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        If objDic(sKey).Cells.Count > 1 Then ' duplicated rows
            ' get the first row
            Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(rngData, objDic(sKey).Cells(1).EntireRow)
            ' get the second row
            If objDic(sKey).Areas.Count = 1 Then
                Set rng2 = Application.Intersect(rngData, objDic(sKey).Cells(2).EntireRow)
            Else
                Set rng2 = Application.Intersect(rngData, objDic(sKey).Areas(2).Cells(1).EntireRow)
            End If
            ' compare two rows
            Set diffRng = MergeRng(diffRng, GetDiff(rng1, rng2))
        End If
    Next
    ' highlight difference
    If Not diffRng Is Nothing Then
        diffRng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
End Sub

' Copare two rows
Function GetDiff(ByRef rng1 As Range, ByRef rng2 As Range) As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng1.Cells.Count
        If rng1.Cells(i).Value <> rng2.Cells(i).Value Then
            Set GetDiff = MergeRng(GetDiff, Application.Union(rng1.Cells(i), rng2.Cells(i)))
        End If
    Next
End Function

' Merge two range
Function MergeRng(ByRef RngAll As Range, ByRef RngSub As Range) As Range
    If RngAll Is Nothing Then
        Set RngAll = RngSub
    ElseIf Not RngSub Is Nothing Then
        Set RngAll = Application.Union(RngAll, RngSub)
    End If
    Set MergeRng = RngAll
End Function



I was looking to do something similar to what this code does for a follow on sub.  Once the duplicates have been identified in Column A, check column B from the 2 rows with duplicate in A for the word Initial, if there then delete the entire row.  I have tried to take the code you provided and modify it to do this, but no luck.  Any way this can be accomplished with small changes to this code?

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?
